# How do I enable zooming in the Win32 Rich Edit control?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm having trouble getting my Rich Edit control to accept the zoom ratio I specify when sending it the `EM_SETZOOM` message.  I create the control using the following line of code:

```
editWrap = CreateWindowEx(0, MSFTEDIT_CLASS, nullptr, ES_EX_ZOOMABLE | ES_MULTILINE |
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_VSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_DISABLENOSCROLL, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    hwnd, nullptr, appInstance, nullptr);
```

Whenever I try to send it the `EM_SETZOOM` message the return value is always `FALSE` no matter what I specify as the `WPARAM` and `LPARAM`.  I also tried putting `ES_EX_ZOOMABLE` as the first parameter of the `CreateWindowEx` call with the same results.

Zooming with the mouse works as expected.  That's not the issue here.  I'm trying to set the zoom programmatically.

I'm using the following code to send the message:

```
SendMessage(getCurrentEditor(), EM_SETZOOM, MAKEWPARAM(64, 0), MAKELPARAM(1, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in the `ES_EX_ZOOMABLE` in the wrong parameter of `CreateWindowEx()`.  You are passing it in the `dwStyle` parameter, but it is an *extended* window style so it needs to be passed in the `dwExStyle` parameter instead, eg:

```
editWrap = CreateWindowEx(ES_EX_ZOOMABLE, MSFTEDIT_CLASS, nullptr, ES_MULTILINE |
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_VSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_DISABLENOSCROLL, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    hwnd, nullptr, appInstance, nullptr);
```

Note that the `EM_SETZOOM` message is only supported on Windows Vista and later, in RichEdit 3.0 and later (you are using 4.1).  You didn't indicate which Windows version you are using, or what your ratio values are set to.  So it is hard to diagnose why exactly `EM_SETZOOM` returns `FALSE`. All that means is that the ratio wasn't accepted, but not *WHY* it wasn't accepted.  Are you able to zoom the RichEdit with the mouse using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>MouseWheel</kbd>? That will tell you whether `ES_EX_ZOOMABLE` is taking effect or not.

On a separate note: you are creating your RichEdit with a width and height of 0! Are you sure that is what you really want?

Comment: I'm running Windows 10.  I set the size of the control later.  Also, I tried passing ES_EX_ZOOMABLE as the first parameter to CreateWindowEx with the same result.

Comment: @DaveF And what are your input values for `EM_SETZOOM`, exactly? And did you try zooming with the mouse yet? These are important details to leave out.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the control won't accept a zoom factor of 64/1.  I found that out by reading the Windows Forms documentation on the [RichTextBox control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.zoomfactor?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-forms-richtextbox-zoomfactor).  The Win32 API documentation just said the zoom factor had to be a number between 1/64 and 64.  The Windows Forms documentation says it has to be "between 1/64 and 64.0, not inclusive".  When I changed my test code to send 63/1 to the control, it worked as expected.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-setzoom) says: *"1/64 < (wParam / lParam) < 64"*.